# Python, redis ошибка wrong number of arguments for hset command

Tags: python, redis

изучаю редис(версия 4.0.2) посредством применения на практике.
Мне нужно по ключу(user_id) хранить словарь настроек.
language: строка с кодом языка
status: строка с местоположением пользователя в меню
country: текущая страна где находится пользователь
currency: текущая валюта пользователя
И в процессе мне необходимо извлекать все или некоторые ключи, менять их, добавлять новые.
нашёл в интернете пример, как раз хорошо подходящий мне:

```
import redis
redis_db = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=1, charset='utf-8', decode_responses=True)
user_id = 847641313
language = 'en'
redis_db.hset(user_id, mapping={"language": language , "status": 0, "counry":'lalalalend', "currency": 'RUB'})
redis_db.hset(user_id, status, 1) # изменение ключа status
redis_db.hset(user_id, mapping={"fav_food": "пицца", "fav_drink": "квас"}) #добавление новых ключей
a = redis_db.hget(user_id, "language") # вернуть значение ключа language
```

попробовал применить, выбрасывается исключение

```
redis.exeption.ResponseError: wrong number of arguments for hset command
```

Использовать команду .set не подходит так как словари как тип данных не допускаются.
Использвать команду .hmset тоже не получается
Вызывается предупреждение

```
redis.hmset is deprecated. Use redis.hset (команда устарела)
```

Пошёл читать документацию, но там про ключ mapping вообще ни слова.
подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.
Спасибо

Comment: Какая, кстати, версия `Redis` у вас конкретно?

Comment: Версия редис 4.0.2
а пример которым я вдохновлялся написан в 3.5.3

Comment: Ну вроде с 4.0.2 должно работать. А на какую строку конкретно всё же ругается? Это важно. И я у вас там кавычек местами добавил, у вас в исходном скрипте так же кавычек может не хватает и дело в этом? Или нет? Хотя в этом случае вроде бы другие ошибки должны быть. Лучше приведите более полный трейс ошибки - со строкой, на которую ругается.

Comment: Для проб я уже использовал только первые пять строк (импорт, настройка, инициализация двух переменных и redis.hset...)
Исключение вызывается в строке с использованием hset. синтаксис проверил досконально. всё на месте (вопрос на сайте набивал вручную поэтому мог ошибится)

Comment: А версию поновее нельзя поставить? Я так понимаю, это какая-то промежуточная была. Возможно, там баги не исправлены переходные. Сейчас уже 6-я линейка актуальная. И в 4-й линейке последняя версия 4.0.14, наверняка там много багов пофиксено. https://download.redis.io/releases/

Comment: Хм, я ставил с помощью команды pip install и думал что поставится последняя актуальная. Спасибо за ответ, буду пробовать

Comment: А вы не путаете версию сервера и версию питоновской библиотеки для связи с сервером? Может, кстати, между ними какая-то несовместимость ещё.

Comment: Версию библиотеки узнал с помощью redis.__version__ эта команда вернула 4.0.2
последний доступный для win64 redis server - 3.0.504 (которым я пользуюсь)
для *nix 6.2.6

Answer (score 1):

Сам спросил - сам отвечаю.
OS windows 10 x64
redis 4.0.2
redis server - 3.0.504 (последний stable от MsOpenTech за 2016 год, новее не нашёл)

команда hset в таком виде будет вызывать исключение:

```
redis_db.hset(user_id, mapping={"language": "rus" , "status": 0, "counry":'lalalalend', "currency": 'RUB'})
```

а в таком будет:

```
redis_db.hset(user_id, mapping={"language": "rus"})
redis_db.hset(user_id, mapping={"status": 0})
redis_db.hset(user_id, mapping={"counry":'lalalalend'})
redis_db.hset(user_id, mapping={"currency": 'RUB'})
```

либо использовать hmset и игнорировать warning о устаревании команды.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно разобрался, для установки множества значений нужно использовать не `hset`, а `hmset`:

```
redis_db.hmset(user_id, mapping={"language": language , "status": 0, "counry":'lalalalend', "currency": 'RUB'})
redis_db.hset(user_id, status, 1) # изменение ключа status
redis_db.hmset(user_id, mapping={"fav_food: "пицца", "fav_drink": "квас"}) #добавление новых ключей
```

Но это касается версий `Redis` до `4.0.0`, а после вообще-то `hset` должна работать со словарём, а `hmset` выдаёт предупреждение, что её использование устарело. Почему `hset` не работает - пока не могу понять.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! использование hmset  вызывает ошибку deprecationWarning 
redis.hmset() is deprecated, Use redis.hset instead.
То есть команда устарела используйте другую

Comment: @MisatoKatsuragi Добавьте этот кейс в вопрос тогда тоже. Какая ошибка выходит в этом случае? Только именно в вопрос, в комментариях нет нормального форматирования, а вопросы можно редактировать и улучшать.

Comment: @MisatoKatsuragi `Warning` - это не ошибка, это предупреждение. Я так понимаю, всё пока работает, но в будущих версиях может перестать. Так что можете пока использовать этот вариант, пока не разберётесь почему `hset` не работает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хорошо, буду использовать hmset. Я просто хотел разобраться как делать правильно с помощью hset, так как информацию не нашёл в документации